# Solid mensuration,Solid Geometry book

Tags: book-recommendation, solid-geometry

Hi I'm an engineering student and i really need your help.....can you please suggest some good books you know regarding **Solid mensuration/Solid Geometry** *good for self studying.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about these two references:

An Introduction to Solid Modeling, by Martti Mantyla : [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716780151)
Geometric Modeling, by Michael Mortenson: [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0831132981)

Comment: Thank you I'll try this ^___^

Comment: If u r aware of its contents, pls provide their names, it would be great favor.